# sql search records where field2 like( field1 with a dash somewhere)

Tags: mysql, sql

a dictionary db with duplicate entries for the word. 1 is correct the 2nd record is different and not correct. The good rows don't have a hyphenated version of field1 anywhere inside of field2.

The bad records all have in the 2nd field (definition) the word from field1 but with a dash or hyphen somewhere in the word.

2 examples of rows to find :A) field1 = Mother, field2 has the word M-other somewhere inside the field definition;  B) field1 = Jackknife, field 2 has Jack-knife somewhere inside the field definition.
So I am thinking of a like clause but like (field 1 with a hyphen anywhere inside the field1 word).

If this is not too confusing i hope someone may have some ideas to try. If you need clarification just let me know. Many thanks in advance for even taking a look.

Comment: Please post sample data and more desired output that illustrate your question?

Answer (score 0):

To get bad rows

```
Select field1, field2
from table
where replace(field2, '-', '') = field1
```

To get good rows

```
Select field1, field2
from table
where field1 not like '%-%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try somethin like that ...

```
-- the bad ones
SELECT *
FROM Table_XY
WHERE REPLACE(field2,'-','') LIKE '%' + field1 + '%'

-- the good ones
SELECT *
FROM Table_XY
WHERE REPLACE(ISNULL(field2,''),'-','') NOT LIKE '%' + field1 + '%' OR
      field2 LIKE '%' + field1 + '%'
```

Comment: I don't think, it's reasonable to use temporary tables for such a trivial query

Comment: it's only to try something ... you do not need the temp_table at all. the only thing you need is the where-clause

Comment: I understand now, you wanted to illustrate, how your query works

Comment: I removed the temporary table. It was only confusing

Comment: Fantastic, thank you all so much. Using WHERE REPLACE(field2,'-','') LIKE '%' + field1 + '%' and the other alternatives was the experienced or genius idea i needed. Markandeya

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the work:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE
  field1 = REPLACE(field2, "-", "") AND
  (SELECT LENGTH(field2) - LENGTH(REPLACE(field2, '-', ''))) >= 1;
```

With this you ensure that both strings are the same without having in mind the dashes. The query also checks that the field2 has dashes, so field1 = Father and field2 = Father won't be selected while field1=Father and field2=F-ather will.

You might add uppercase transformation in the query if you want it to be case unsensitive.

[**SQL Fiddle (example).**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f191/3)